# Can somebody please briefly explain to me what's happening with the IntStream?

Tags: java, java-8

I looked up multiple examples online but I just can't seem to grasp what's happening here. When the program prints out the current player and the scores, it's not apparent to me where these are stored. I'm a begginer and I was told to analyze this piece of code to help "better understand" our current class project.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public interface PigDice {
    public static void main(String... arguments) {
        final int maxScore = 100;
        final int playerCount = 2;
        final String[] yesses = { "y", "Y", "" };

        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        final Random random = new Random();

        final int[] safeScore = new int[2];
        final int[] score = new int[2];

        IntStream.iterate(0, player -> (player + 1) % playerCount).map(player -> {
            boolean isRolling = true;
            while (isRolling) {
                System.out.printf("Player %d: (%d, %d) Rolling? (y/n) ", player, safeScore[player], score[player]);
            isRolling = safeScore[player] + score[player] < maxScore
                    && Arrays.asList(yesses).contains(scanner.nextLine());
                if (isRolling) {
                    final int rolled = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
                    System.out.printf("Rolled %d\n", rolled);
                    if (rolled == 1) {
                        System.out.printf("Bust! You lose %d but keep %d\n\n", score[player], safeScore[player]);
                        return -1;
                    } else {
                        score[player] += rolled;
                    }
                } else {
                    safeScore[player] += score[player];
                    if (safeScore[player] >= maxScore) {
                        return player;
                    }
                    System.out.printf("Sticking with %d\n\n", safeScore[player]);
                }
            }
            score[player] = 0;
            return -1;
        }).filter(player -> player > -1).findFirst().ifPresent(
                player -> System.out.printf("\n\nPlayer %d wins with a score of %d", player, safeScore[player]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate-int-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator- ?

Comment: Perhaps you should start with The Java Tutorials: [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Comment: I hope it wasn't a teacher who threw this code at a beginner programmer.  It's hardly what I would call easy to understand.

Comment: This code is definitely much more awkward to read with lambdas.  I hope this isn't real code period.

Comment: I agree with Louis and VGR. The long multi-line lambda is a bad code smell. So is this use of streams instead of a straightforward loop. This is quite an obscure way to write what is a pretty simple program.

Comment: @Paul I tried but it was insanely hard to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand what this code does, I'd first apply a couple key refactorings:

1. Promote all of `main()`'s local variables to static variables of the `PigDice` class.
2. Extract the big multi-line lambda that's passed to `map()` into a static method of the `PigDice` class. Call this method `turn()`:

   ```
   static int turn(int player) {
       ...
   }
   ```

The stream pipeline now looks like this:

```
    IntStream.iterate(0, player -> (player + 1) % playerCount)
             .map(PigDice::turn)
             .filter(player -> player > -1)
             .findFirst()
             .ifPresent(
                player ->
                    System.out.printf("\n\nPlayer %d wins with a score of %d",
                        player, safeScore[player]));
```

The `IntStream.iterate()` method produces a stream of `int` values starting with the provided initial value, which is zero in this case. Subsequent values are computed by the lambda expression. Here, that expression adds one and computes the remainder with `playerCount`, which is two in this example. The result is a stream of values 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ... representing the player number whose turn it is.

The `map()` stage passes each of these values to the `turn()` method, which executes all the game logic. But if you boil down this logic, basically it returns -1 if there is no winner and it returns its input argument (the current player number) if that player has won. This results in a stream -1, -1, -1, -1, ... 0 if player 0 has won (or 1 for the last value if player 1 has won).

The result stream from `map()` is only part of the story. The actual game logic operates by **side effects** on the game state, which is maintained in the captured variables `scanner`, `random`, `score`, and `safeScore`.

The `filter()` stage passes through only values that are greater than -1, thus it drops all those leading -1 values while the game is progressing, producing a value only after a player has won.

The `findFirst()` stage takes the first element and then terminates the stream. That's why the game eventually terminates.

Now, `findFirst()` returns an `OptionalInt` which contains the number of the winning player. In general it could be empty, but in this case it never will be empty because `iterate()` produces an infinite stream. Since it's never empty, the lambda expression inside of `ifPresent()` is always executed and is passed the number of the winning player; this prints out the final game result.

That's basically how this works.

Note that, as I and others have pointed out in comments, there are several bad code smells and anti-patterns here, plus a few bugs. I strongly recommend **not** using this as an example of good lambda and streams coding practices.

Comment: Amazingly thorough. Thank you.